# Submonoid of the set of integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

Let us consider $(\mathbb Z,+)$ as a monoid. Is it true that all submonoids of this are finitely generated as a monoid? If yes how should I prove it (any hint). If not what will be a counterexample?

Thank you.

Comment: See this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1105549)

Comment: @J.-E.Pin How to show that "It is simple to show that for any set of positive integers with GCD 1, there are only finitely many positive integers which cannot be written as a finite sum of elements of the set"

Comment: Use [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézout%27s_identity).

Comment: Yes but in Bezout's identity the coefficients may be negative, how should I overcome that?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: consider the set of irreducible elements and their greatest common divisor.

Comment: What do you mean by irreducible elements?

Comment: A nonzero element is irreducible if it is not the sum of two nonzero elements.