# Power of a group of languages

Tags: regular-language, infinite-groups

I need help finding and proving the power of the group of languages A:

A={L|L=L* and L is over $\Sigma\ = \{1\}\ $}

I was thinking of the fact that if L=L*  - if $1^k\ ,1^p \in L  $ then,

m=k+p , $1^m \in L\\$

but im not sure how to continue from here, thank you in advance:)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, basically that's all that could be said:

Given a language $L$ on alphabet $\{1\}$, and let $N_L:=\{n:1^n\in L\}$, then we have $N_{L^*}$ is the *submonoid* of $(\Bbb N,+,0)$ generated by $N_L$, so that $L=L^*$ iff $N_L$ is already a *submonoid*, that is, if it contains $0$ and is closed under addition, (i.e. $L$ contains the empty word and is closed under concatenation - including repetition).

Based on e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395166/is-the-set-of-submonoids-of-bbb-n-countable), we conclude that every submonoid of $\Bbb N$ is *finitely generated*, and consequently, $L=L^*$ iff $L=(w_1|w_2|\dots|w_k)^*$ for some words $w_i\in 1^*$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to proceed

Comment: Hmm, my original idea seems to be wrong.. I will update or delete my answer, sorry.